# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode' error when writing to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to read JSON from a file and insert it into a MySQL database. But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "loopedadd.py", line 44, in <module>
cursor.execute(add_record, data_record)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 536, in execute
stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I have tried connecting with `use_unicode=True, charset='utf8'` to no avail.

Any help on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
import mysql.connector
import Queue, json

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="root",
host="192.168.1.64",
password="....",
database="records",
port=3306)
print("connected")
cursor = cnx.cursor()


queue = Queue.Queue()
content = json.load(open("data.txt","r"))

for jsonobj in content:
    queue.put(jsonobj)

add_record = (
    "INSERT INTO records "
    "(id, timestamp, location, value, unit) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

while not queue.empty():

    values = queue.get()

    data_record = (values['id'], values['timestamp'], 
    values['location'], values['reading'], values['unit'])

    cursor.execute(add_record, data_record)
    cnx.commit()
    queue.task_done()
```

Comment: show more traceback, also this is a highly inefficient way to load data into a DB

Comment: `operation` is a function. I suggest you work out why `operation` is not a function and not a (presumably) string.

Comment: @aws_apprentice I have edited the post to include the full traceback. I am running an experiment to benchmark database performance, hence the single write and commits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try [MySQLdb](http://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/) and now it works fine. No idea what the problem was with [MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python.html)